How can i Render a foreach Loop in MudBlazor MudTable RowTemplate
I have MudExpansionPanels in my code which when placed i need them to show a Table of its related data. But am having an issue where by the Table is not rendering the correctly all items are displayed far left and leaving chunk of spaces on the right as shown in picture
How its showing
The table covers the whole area but all the contents are on the left only, below is the code
<MudCardContent>
    <MudText> <b>Continous Assessments For Semester 1</b></MudText>
    @if (currentAssessments?.Count(c => c.Semester.IsFirstSemester == true) > 0)
    {
        <MudExpansionPanels>
            @foreach (var courseGroup in currentAssessments.GroupBy(c => c.Course.CourseName))
            {
                @if (courseGroup.Any(c => c.Semester.IsFirstSemester == true))
                {
                    <MudExpansionPanel Text=@($"{courseGroup.Key}")>
                        <MudTable Items="courseGroup" Dense="true" Bordered="true" Striped="true" Hover="true">
                            <HeaderContent>
                                <MudTr>
                                    <MudTh style="width: 40%;">Assessment Name</MudTh>
                                    <MudTh style="width: 30%;">Assessment Type</MudTh>
                                    <MudTh style="width: 30%;">Grade</MudTh>
                                </MudTr>
                            </HeaderContent>
                            <RowTemplate>
                                @foreach (var assessment in context.Course.Assessments)
                                {
                                    <MudTr>
                                        <MudTd style="width: 40%;">@assessment.Description</MudTd>
                                        <MudTd style="width: 30%;">@assessment.AssessmentType.AssessmentDescription</MudTd>
                                        <MudTd style="width: 30%;">
                                            @if (assessment.IsVisible == true)
                                            {
                                                @($"{assessment.AssessmentScores.FirstOrDefault()?.Score} / {assessment.MaximumScore}")
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                @($"_ / {assessment.MaximumScore}")
                                            }
                                        </MudTd>
                                    </MudTr>
                                }
                            </RowTemplate>
                        </MudTable>
                    </MudExpansionPanel>
                }
                else
                {
                    <MudAlert Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Info">No items</MudAlert>
                }
            }
        </MudExpansionPanels>
    }
    else
    {
        <MudAlert Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Info" Severity="Severity.Info">No Assessments Found</MudAlert>
    }
</MudCardContent>

Am expecing the table contents to be spread across the entire length of the MudExpansionPanel as i need to fit in other data into the table.
